# How can I match substrings of a list's elements in another list?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

For some reason, I can't seem to figure this out using Lambda (I could use loops but I'd rather learn it in lambda).

I have two lists.  I'm trying to find a string from the second list inside any string of the first list.

```
[Test]
public void CheckInsideList()
{
    var mainList = new List<string>() { "looking_for_specific_word", "has_specific_word", "doesnt_have_word" };
    var reservedList = new List<string>() { "specific", "Bob", "Loblaws" };

    //var returnValue = mainList.Where(d => d.Contains(reservedList));
    Assert.Greater(returnValue.Count, 0);
}
```

I'm not sure if I should be using `Contains` or `IndexOf`.

I'm expecting to get back "looking_for_specific_word" and "has_specific_word" from `mainList`.

Comment: `var returnValue = mainList.Where(d => reservedList.Contains(d));`

Comment: The sample strings suggest that you want to find matching _words_ not substrings. Does "little bobby tables" match?

Comment: I would say yes to your "little bobby tables" example.  I think Ant P updated my title accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any` + `Contains`:

1a)

```
var returnValue = mainList.Where(d => reservedList.Any(d.Contains));
```

which is nearly the same as:

1b)

```
var returnValue = mainList.Where(d => reservedList.Any(r=> d.Contains(r)));
```

or with `IndexOf` (allows to compare case insensitive):

2)

```
var returnValue = mainList
    .Where(d => reservedList
        .Any(r => d.IndexOf(r, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is this:

```
mainList.Where(m => reservedList.Any(r => m.Contains(r));
```

Comment: I'm trying to find cases where a string inside reservedList in contained inside mainList

Comment: @Lareau Are you sure? Your question makes it look like you are trying to find cases where a string inside reservedList is contained in *an element of* mainList. If that's not the case, you should clarify.

Comment: @Lareau You want the *whole* string from reservedList to match a *whole* string from mainList, or is only a partial match acceptable? It might be useful to show in the OP what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @Lareau This snippet gives that result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
var result = mainList.Where(x => reservedList.Any(z => x.Contains(z)));
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I65SBm).